# How to let TextChanged event convert only complete numbers, not partial entries?

Tags: c#, winforms

```
private void textBox3_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (textBox3.Text == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("אנא הכנס נתונים בתיבות הטקסט מצד שמאל כדי להמשיך");
            timer1.Stop();
            button2.Enabled = false;
            button3.Enabled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            IsItANumber(textBox3.Text);
            textBox3_text_valid = Convert.ToDouble(textBox3.Text);

            if (textBox3_text_valid > 0)
            {
                textbox3_value = textBox3.Text;
                Options_DB.Set_textBox3_time(textbox3_value);
                timer.Start();

            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
    } 
}
```

The problem in the `TextBox.TextChanged` event is that sometimes I want to enter a value of 60 or 90 or 100 but once I type 6 or only 7 it will start the timer already before I can type 0 after it so it will be 60 or 70.

I need to make it so it will count as a valid number also if its 1 digit or more.
If I type 6 its valid 6 if I type 60 it will be 60.

Comment: Does it have to be textchanged event which triggers timer. Could you use leave event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can handle [LostFocus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.lostfocus%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [Leave](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.leave%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event instead of `TextChanged`

```
private void textBox3_LostFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   ...
}
```

Comment: Or use the `Validated` event.